# Error: "ambiguous symbol; std::vector<_Ty>"

Tags: visual-c++, vector, c++-cli, visual-c++-2010

While I was compiling a written C++/CLI Windows Forms application in Visual C++ 2010, I faced this error: `ambiguous symbol; std::vector<_Ty>`

Here is part of my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

/////// global data of algorithm ////////
bool flag =false;
vector<string>sent;
int token=0;
struct lexicon
{
    string name;
    string type;//noun, verb, particle
    string subtype;//proper name, noun, pronoun
    string num;//1:singular 2:double 3:plural
    string gender;//f:female m:male
    string speaker;//1:I,we 2:you 3:they,she,he,it
    string defined;//true:defined false:undefined
    string tran;//for verbs--> 0:intransitive 1:transitive 2:ditransitive
    string res;
};
 vector<lexicon> stat;
 lexicon temp;
 std::vector<lexicon> dec;

 ////////search inside the dictionary
 void search(string word)
 {
for(vector <lexicon>::iterator i=dec.begin(); i!=dec.end();++i)
{
    if(word==(*i).name)
    {
        stat.push_back((*i));
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
}

//if the word is not found in the lexcion--> end the program
if(flag==false)
     {
     MessageBox::Show( "This word is not in lexicon \n");
     //cout<<"This word is not in lexicon"<<endl<<endl;
    //--getch(); 
    //--exit(1);
}
flag=false;
 }
 public ref class CExercise : public Form
 {
 private:
  Label ^ lblTitle;
  ComboBox ^ cbxAcademicDisciplines;

TextBox^  textBox1;
    Label^  label1;
Button^  End_Button;
Button^  Next_Button;
   public:
     CExercise()
     {
InitializeComponent();
    }

   private:
    void InitializeComponent()
    {
    textBox1 = (gcnew TextBox());
label1 = gcnew Label();
    End_Button = gcnew Button();
    Next_Button = gcnew Button();
    End_Button->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 10,          System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        // End_Button->ForeColor = White;
        End_Button->Location = Point(142, 216);

        End_Button->Size = System::Drawing::Size(120, 30);
        End_Button->TabIndex = 2;
        End_Button->Text = "End of sentence";
        End_Button->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        End_Button->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,   &CExercise::End_Button_Click);
        Controls->Add(End_Button);
    }
private: System::Void Next_Button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^    e) {

          int selectedIndex = comboBox1->SelectedIndex;
              Object^ selectedItem = comboBox1->SelectedItem;
          Object^ textboxdata = textBox1->Text;
          comboBox1->SelectedIndex = 0;//////////////
         // lexicon temp;
          MarshalString ( textboxdata->ToString(), temp.name);
          sent.push_back(temp.name);
          token++;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.type);
          selectedItem = comboBox7->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.subtype);
          selectedItem = comboBox3->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.num);
          selectedItem = comboBox6->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.gender);
          selectedItem = comboBox5->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.speaker);
          selectedItem = comboBox4->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.defined);
         selectedItem = comboBox9->SelectedItem;
          MarshalString ( selectedItem->ToString(), temp.tran);
         // dec.push_back(temp);
          comboBox1->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox7->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox3->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox6->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox5->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox4->SelectedIndex = 0;
          comboBox9->SelectedIndex = 0;
          textBox1->Text = " ";


      MessageBox::Show( "Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem->ToString() + "\n" +
      "Index: " + selectedIndex.ToString() );
     }
      };
   int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
         HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
         LPSTR lpCmdLine,
         int nCmdShow)
 {
   Application::Run(gcnew CExercise);


    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You should swap the `c++` tag for whatever microsoft specific version of C++ you are actually using (c++.net, managed c++, CX and so on).

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: the code you listed is not strict C++, evident by the user of `gcnew` and the `^` thing. It is some dialect or bastardisation, you'll get a better answer if you mark this question with the correct language tag.

Comment: Oh, thank you I forgot, and there was someone edited it.

Comment: Surely you still get the error with about 90% of that commented out.  Try to make us a smaller file with the same problem, it's hard to look through that much code when we don't have the help of the compiler or debugger like you do.  That might even help you find the problem and solution.